# Passing DataView to controller with javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I am trying to make the view communicate with the controller to update values (database) using javascript, mvc and Asp.Net
here is my view `

```
    function updateRejectType() {
       $("#btnvalider").click(function ()
        var IdRTDoc = <%: ViewData["IdRTDoc"] %> ;
        var strTypeDocument=<%:ViewData["RejectedTypesList"]  %>;
        var strLabel= <%: ViewData["strLabel"] %> ;

    $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '<%= Url.Action("UpdateRejectedType", "RejectedTypes") %>',
             data: "IdRTDoc=" + IdRTDoc +"DocumentType"+ strTypeDocument + "Label" + strLabel,
             processData: false,
             cache: false,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             complete: function () {
            alert("updated");
                                   },
             success: function () {

             error: FailureFunction
                     });


     success: function (result, request) {
                 alert("Mis à jour avec succès");
                 SuccessValider();
             },
             failure: FailureFunctionUpdate
         });

       }

       function SuccessValider(){
        window.open('../Home/About', '_parent');
 }

 function FailureFunctionUpdate() {
     alert("Problème survenu dans update !");
 }


</script>
```

`
which contains the function

> updateRejectType()
>          that I call here

```
<input type="button" a class="lien_bloc_gris" onclick="updateRejectType()" value="valider" name="btnvalider"><span> </span></a></input>
```

And here is my controller method

```
public virtual ActionResult UpdateRejectedType(int IdRTDoc, int strDocumentType, string strLabel)
    {
        try
        {

            RejectedTypesViewModel obj = new RejectedTypesViewModel();
            obj.DocumentType = strDocumentType;
            obj.Label = strLabel;



            var result = repository.RejectedTypesUpdate("All", obj);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Shared");
        }
    }
```

When I clic on the button, nothing happends.What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Is `UpdateRejectedType` actually getting hit?

Answer (score 0):

Since your button has `onclick="updateRejectType()"` attribute, you don't need to bind the click event with `$("#btnvalider").click(function ()`. You also missed `&` and `=` in the `data` option. Change your script as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateRejectType() {
        var IdRTDoc = <%: ViewData["IdRTDoc"] %> ;
        var strTypeDocument=<%:ViewData["RejectedTypesList"]  %>;
        var strLabel= <%: ViewData["strLabel"] %> ;

        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '<%= Url.Action("UpdateRejectedType", "RejectedTypes") %>',
             data: "IdRTDoc=" + IdRTDoc +"&DocumentType="+ strTypeDocument + "&Label=" + strLabel,
             processData: false,
             cache: false,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             complete: function () {
                 alert("updated");
             },
             success: function (result, request) {
                 alert("Mis à jour avec succès");
                 SuccessValider();
             },
             error: FailureFunctionUpdate
        });
    }

    function SuccessValider(){
        window.open('../Home/About', '_parent');
    }

    function FailureFunctionUpdate() {
        alert("Problème survenu dans update !");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this passing your data:

```
data: {IdRTDoc: IdRTDoc,  DocumentType: strTypeDocument, Label: strLabel},
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't work I think that the error is in the function but I cannot see it